# make vertical fill inside multicols environment

Tags: enumerate, multicol, fill

I want to have the right column not to be stretched by using `\vfill`. The source code I used is this.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $ x^{2} - 7x + 10 = 0 $
        \item $ 2x^{2} - 5x - 9 = 0 $
        \item $ 7x^{2} + x - 1 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + 4x + 4 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + x + 1 = 0 $
    \end{enumerate}
    \vfill
\end{multicols}
```

The code above will produce something like this
[image: the right column is stretched]

We can see that the right column is stretched. I don't want it to be like this. So I add `\vfill` below the enumerate environment, but this doesn't fix anything.

I also try using `enumerate*`, but it seems that it doesn't automatically break after point c).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multicols has a command for that (see page 4).  `\raggedcolumns` can be used locally (inside the environment) or globally (in the preamble).

You can also use `\vspace*{\fill}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $ x^{2} - 7x + 10 = 0 $
        \item $ 2x^{2} - 5x - 9 = 0 $
        \item $ 7x^{2} + x - 1 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + 4x + 4 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + x + 1 = 0 $
    \end{enumerate}
    \raggedcolumns
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $ x^{2} - 7x + 10 = 0 $
        \item $ 2x^{2} - 5x - 9 = 0 $
        \item $ 7x^{2} + x - 1 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + 4x + 4 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + x + 1 = 0 $
        \item[]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Note that the other answer below makes more sense since it will auto adjust the columns. Essentially, what you are trying to do is fill the vertical gap. You can use the suggested `\vspace*{\fill}` or `\vfill\null` or `\vfill\mbox{}` after your enumerate.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $ x^{2} - 7x + 10 = 0 $
        \item $ 2x^{2} - 5x - 9 = 0 $
        \item $ 7x^{2} + x - 1 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + 4x + 4 = 0 $
        \item $ x^{2} + x + 1 = 0 $
    \end{enumerate}
    \vspace*{\fill}% or \vfill\null or \vfill\mbox{}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: So we have to count items and add as many empty items to have an even number. Not really elegant.